# Backbone.js: Run and display api results on keydown event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am programming with Backbone.js I am trying to run an API request when the user types in a query in the search box. However nothing happens when I type in a query.

Here is my JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){

var SearchList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/taco?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Cbrand_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_id&appId=26952a04&appKey=78e2b31849de080049d26dc6cf4f338c",

    initialize: function(){
        this.bind("reset", function(model, options){
        console.log("Inside event");
        console.log(model);
        });
    },
    //** 1. Function "parse" is a Backbone function to parse the response properly
    parse:function(response){
        //** return the array inside response, when returning the array
        //** we left to Backone populate this collection
        return response.hits;
    }

});

// The main view of the application
var App = Backbone.View.extend({



    initialize: function () {

        this.model = new SearchList();

        this.list = $('#listing');

    },
    el: 'document',

    events: {

    "keydown" : "prepCollection"
    },
    prepCollection: function(){
        var name = $('input').val();
       var newUrl = "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/" + name + "?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Cbrand_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_id&appId=26952a04&appKey=78e2b31849de080049d26dc6cf4f338c";
        this.model.set("url", newUrl);
        this.model.fetch({
            success: function (response, xhr) {
                console.log("Inside success");
                console.log(response.toJSON());
            },
            ERROR: function (errorResponse) {
                console.log(errorResponse)
            }
        });
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);

    },

    render: function(){
        var terms = this.model;
        terms.each(function (term) {
            this.list.append("<li>" + term.get('field')["brand_name"] + "</li>")
        }, this);

    }
});
       var app = new App();
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Interactive Food Guide</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="searchBox"> <br/><br/>
        </div>
        <ul id="listing"></ul>
    </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Backbone and Underscore -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <!-- apps functionality -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url` is a property of the model, not an attribute. Think of attributes as things you might persist to the server.

Change:

```
this.model.set("url", newUrl);
```

To:

```
this.model.url = newUrl;
```

Note that `url` can also be a function which returns a string, and that there is a default function already there which works for some more typical REST cases: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url

Also JS variables and object keys are case-sensitive, so your key should be `error` nor `ERROR`.

After running the project I noticed a couple of other things wrong:

1. `el: 'document'` - This is the whole document including the head, Backbone works with the `body` or things within it. Fix this by changing it to `el: 'body'`
2. You were trying to access the `field` attribute - it is actually called fields and you can access it like so `term.get('fields').brand_name`

Other bonus fixes: Clear the list before appending new results, `_.throttle` `prepCollection` so that if letters are typed fast then it will only do 2 searches (one at the beginning and one at the end of the input). Change to `_.debounce` to only do one search at the end of the input.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/2nLezvmg/1/

Comment: It still doesn't work when I change it to this.model.url =newUrl;

Comment: Thank you, I would now like to implement a functionality where I add an individual food Item to a different list when I click on it. This second list would then track the calories of each food item. How would I go about getting the information for a clicked item in the current results list?